# Excel VBA copy from sheet1 cell to sheet2 cell with format

Tags: excel, vba

I have a very simple problem but my lack of knowledge blocks me.
I need to copy the values and the format of a cell from sheet1 to sheet2.
The cell's row and column are changed by a loop.
This works for me:

```
Sheets("SLAVE").Cells(slave_y, slave_x) = Sheets("MASTER").Cells(master_y, master_x)
```

but it only copies values and not formats.

I tried this

```
Sheets("MASTER").Cells(master_y, master_x).Copy Sheets("SLAVE").Cells(slave_y, slave_x)
```

but it copies me formulas (which I don't want)

Is there a way to specify to this line of code above to copy only values and formats?

Thank you!

Comment: `Sheets("MASTER").Cells(master_y, master_x).Copy Sheets("SLAVE").Cells(slave_y, slave_x)` and then `Sheets("SLAVE").Cells(slave_y, slave_x) = Sheets("SLAVE").Cells(slave_y, slave_x)`?

Answer (score 0):

Copy your values to clipoboard and then paste both, values and formats.

```
Sheets("MASTER").Cells(master_y, master_x).Copy
Sheets("SLAVE").Cells(slave_y, slave_x).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
Sheets("SLAVE").Cells(slave_y, slave_x).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thank you for the very quick reply! It works, but it's really slow (I have hundreds of row). I read that copying to clipboard is slow and in fact it is! Is there a way to copy directly to the slave cell, values and formats?

Comment: Working cell by cell is always slow in Excel. The preferred way is to copy the entire range and paste. Example: Sheets("MASTER").Range("A10:A10000").Copy. This will improve the performance dramatically.

Comment: I can't do that, because my code actually reads the whole master sheet and creates several slave sheets to print.

Answer (score 0):

We don't know how your ranges look like and if it is possible to copy/paste without loop. Maybe you can try something like this:

```
 Sub copy()

 With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = False
      .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
      .EnableEvents = False
      .DisplayStatusBar = False
 End With
 On Error Resume Next

 Dim mRng As Range   ' master Range
 Dim sRng As Range   ' slave Range

 Set mRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("masterSheetNameHere").Range("A1:A100")
 Set sRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("slaveSheetNameHere").Range("B1:B100")

 sRng.Value(11) = mRng.Value(11) ' 11 argument means values and formats

 On Error GoTo 0
 With Application
      .ScreenUpdating = True
      .Calculation = xlAutomatic
      .EnableEvents = True
      .DisplayStatusBar = True
 End With

 End Sub
```

**UPDATE**
In your code (based on your file trial 07.xlsm) you have some possible performance issues. E.g. instead:

```
 Sheets("MASTER").Range(Cells(j, MastCol1).Address()).Copy
 Sheets(nomeFoglio).Range(Cells(y, DestColE1).Address()).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteColumnWidths
```

you can simply use:

```
 Sheets(nomeFoglio).Range(Cells(y, DestColE1).Address).ColumnWidth = Sheets("MASTER").Range(Cells(j, MastCol1).Address).ColumnWidth
```

Another **more important issue** is: do you really need apply your format cell by cell? It seems that your entire column has the same format. So you can possible use your fast code to copy values only and after all set format for entire columns (or in reverse order). One more thing- can't you copy range in row (3 cells in a row at once instead make copy operation for each cell)? The last one thing- if everything will not work, you should read about storing your data into an array and save from it into sheet at once.

Comment: Hi and thank you very much for your inputs! I've uploaded my file here https://www.dropbox.com/s/8nx2td4nkyr5807/trial%2007.xlsm?dl=0

Comment: please have a look. In the main module "crea_fogli_e_colonne" I commented these rows of code `Sheets(nomeFoglio).Cells(y, DestColE1) = Sheets("MASTER").Cells(j, MastCol1)` because it's fast but only copies values. I want to copy other properties as well but it's slow! I would like to speed it up!

Comment: Sorry, you must try adapt the code posted above by yourself. Is something incomprehensible in my possible solution? Ciao!

Comment: Ciao Rafal, ok, I'll have a better look at that!

Comment: I've been able to do that.

Comment: Sheets(nomeFoglio).Range(Cells(y, DestColE1).Address()).Value(11) = Sheets("MASTER").Range(Cells(j, MastCol1).Address()).Value(11)    it's a bit faster but still takes 15 seconds for 200/300 rows!

Comment: In my opinion if .Value = .Value isn't much faster than several Copy/PasteSpecial then something time-consuming is in other lines of code. In your case I would comment each section one by one to be sure where the problem really is.

Comment: ok, I'll try that but for now it seems the speed problem is that. Thank you for all your help! I'll try to post this problem to an Excel forum, is it ok for you?

Comment: @Dolphin975 First of all your macro takes on my 6-year HP laptop max~ 2 second to be completed- maybe you have some Excel files in the background and you should turn off automatic calculations and events as I posted in my answer. The second - read my updated answer.

Comment: Rafal, thank you for your feedback! It seems strange to me as well! I also rebooted my PC and still have the same slow speed. My PC is pretty decent: i7 5820K, 32 GB ram, SSD 500GB m2, RTX 4000... all is pretty powerful. Don't understand where the problem is!

Comment: I followed your advice and with a friend's help, I set format for entire columns. Now it's really fast! :) Thank you!